# Best way to document (phpdoc) generators (methods that yield)

Tags: php, generator, phpdoc, php-5.5

What is the best way to document, for phpdocumentor2, a method that is a generator.

I don't think `@return` really works for `yield`, but I can't seem to find any proper alternative.

Is it just a matter of waiting for phpdoc to catch up?

Comment: IMHO `@return` is appropriate, since it denotes what you get back from the generator.

Comment: As of now there is no spec'd way to do this. You are correct in that `@return` is certainly incorrect. Most likely the syntax will be either `@yield V` or `@return Generator<V>`, maybe with the ability to specify K, S and R as well. See also https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/issues/5

Comment: @NikiC Your reply should really be posted as an answer.

Answer (score 42):

I went with `@return Generator|SomeObject[]`, where `SomeObject` is the thing being yielded.

PhpStorm handles this well too, as it now normally hints `Generator` methods and when iterated it hints `SomeObject` methods.

(Still, I would prefer a native `@yield`.)

**Update (2023):** nowadays there's good support for the new format `Generator<SomeObject>` as well, as suggested by Thanh in a below answer. Duplicating it here for visibility.

Comment: Editor hints: Netbeans just need a `SomeObject` (or `\SomeObject`) in `@return` to prompt SomeObject's methods. PhpStorm needs extra `[]` at the end of type (`SomeObject[]`). So I thinkbest option is to write it like @Robbert wrote: `@return Generator|\SomeObject[]`.

Comment: What about `Generator->getReturn()`, as of PHP 7?

Comment: That's going to be even harder to hint. What do you suggest?

Comment: That's a very clever solution!

Comment: This should be the marked answer. Really helpful. Thank you.

Comment: It is unfortunate, but adopting this has really bad consequences: from a static analysis point of view, the `|` means "or", this leads to the fact that a method declared with `@return Generator|SomeObject[]` means that it **either** return a Generator of untyped data, **or** strictly an `array` of `SomeObject`.

Comment: @pmaruszczyk that is especially wrong.. `SomeObject` means one specific object, whereas `SomeObject[]` is an list of (possibly many) objects. The behaviour in Netbeans you described sounds like a bug.

Answer (score 12):

[From the PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php#language.generators.object):

> When a generator function is called for the first time, an object of
>   the internal Generator class is returned.

So strictly speaking, `@return Generator` would be correct, although not super descriptive of what you can expect to get back when you iterate over the generator.

Answer (score 7):

It's also possible to type the Generator

```
@return Generator<array|int>
```

Comment: This ^^ PhpStorm handles this with any `Traversable` return type